# Looking for some harmonic justification of chord progression: F G Bbm --> F?

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-progressions, tonal

I have found this pretty melancholic cadence ( F-G-Bbm--> F) in many songs. For example in the beautiful Alan Parsons's "Since the last Goodbye", (in the form Db-Eb-Gbm--> Db). In this song the cadence is repeatedly modulated to different keys.

To accomplish these chords one need at least two chromatic alterations, so I wonder which are really the tonic. It appears to me that the tonic is F and Bbm is the dominant because it appears to lend and relax to F, and because by adding a minor 7ª: Bbm7 sounds as well good .
Nevertheless  it appears very strange to me to have a dominant that is constructed on the IV degree ( that should be subdominant) and moreover: of the minor kind.

Answer (score 4):

Looking into the song and playing the progression myself I instantly noticed the connection between the words he was singing, the feelings he was trying to provoke, and the chord progression.

It starts on a hopeful and stable Db major chord which plays a majority of the song (and many of the other chords include Db in them according to the chord charts I'm reading). He moves hopefully up a whole step to Eb major (sometimes written Eb over Db), symbolizing the hope he still has for his lost love. This change happens over the word "goodbye" which also sounds natural when sung higher like that. Then when he sings "wrong" the chord changes to Gb minor (again written over Db) which symbolizing his sinking feeling at the realization he'll never get it back. Not only are we moving into a minor chord instead of a major chord like we would expect, but it's a chromatic movement downward by half step. It gives a very sinking feeling to the line and makes you want to sigh before we come back to rest comfortably on Db.

You could almost think of Db as the V chord and Gb minor as the tonic, symbolizing the unresolved nature of our protagonists dilemma. Yet while technically that works it still sounds like an unresolved cadence in context to the rest of the chords and the focus on Db. There's a lot of things going on here meant to be unresolved, nostalgic, longing, hopeful, etc. All the harmony is in service to the song.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should reserve the term 'dominant' for the V chord in a key.

I can only answer your question with another.  Why SHOULDN'T this progression be OK?  It can be described as I, II, IVm, I.  Yes, two of these are chromatic chords.  Chromatic chords are common, and are perfectly 'allowed'.  This sequence works particularly well over a tonic pedal - F, G/F, Bbm/F, F - but is good with root position chords too.  It's easy to arrange with smooth voice-leading.   Add it to your bag of tricks.